# Showing different output for two almost same code

Tags: c, printf

In the following two codes I cannot understand the problem.
First code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    int num1, num2;

    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    printf("I LOVE MY INDIA\n"); //here is '\n' after the statement
    printf("%d", num1/num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here if the inputs are `num1=2` and `num2=0` then in gcc compiler the output is:

> I LOVE MY INDIA
>      Floating point exception (core dumped)

But for the second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    int num1, num2;

    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    printf("I LOVE MY INDIA"); //here is no '\n'
    printf("%d", num1/num2);

    return 0;
}
```

For same input as before this is showing:

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

In between these two codes there is only one difference. In the 1st one there is a `\n` after `I LOVE MY INDIA` and in the 2nd code there is no `\n`.
Please explain why `I LOVE MY INDIA` is not being displayed in the 2nd code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the standard output (`stdout`) is line buffered.

In first case, the newline `\n` in the `printf()` causes the output buffer to be flushed to the output *before* the crash happens. So, you got to see the print statement.

OTOH, in the second case, lack of the `\n` causes the buffer to hold the data, and the next statement causes the exception and an abnormal termination of the program. So, the buffered data did not get a chance to be flushed to the output terminal. Hence, you got no *visual* output.

That said, a division by zero causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and strictly speaking, your program cannot be relied upon to produce any expected output.